# Python: how to replace an element in a list with all elements from another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in Python that look like this:

```
 lst = [1, '?2']
 replace_lst1 = ['a','b','c']
```

For each occurrence of `'?2'` in `lst`, I would like to replace it with each element from `replace_lst1` thereby producing a list of lists as follows:

```
res = [ [1,'a'], 
        [1,'b'],
        [1,'c'] ]
```

Similarly, if I have the following lists:

```
lst = [1, '?2','?3']
replace_lst1 = ['a','b','c']
replace_lst2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I would like to replace `'?2'` with each element from `replace_lst1` and `'?3'` with each element from `replace_lst2`, thereby exploring all possible permutations. The result should look like this:

```
res = [ [1,'a','A'], 
        [1,'a','B'],
        [1,'a','C'],
        [1,'b','A'], 
        [1,'b','B'],
        [1,'b','C'],
        [1,'c','A'], 
        [1,'c','B'],
        [1,'c','C'] ]
```

It would be great if you could provide me with some suggestions how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of this? Do you ever have `replace_lst3`?

Comment: are the `?N` format mandatory? shall it begin at `1`? it's definitively possible to do what you want, but it looks pretty weird and won't be elegant...

Comment: Unless this is being imposed on you from some external place, I would strongly advise you to use a different data model. What you want can be done very elegantly with a single line of code, but not if you define your data like this.

Comment: In this context, permutations has a specific meaning, and it isn't what you want

Comment: There is no `replace_lst3`. The `?X` format is given. It doesn't begin at 1, actually, the lists are strings. I simplified the things for illustrative purposes. As for the data structure, I'd like the result to be a list of lists since I'll have to do some operations on the result and with this data structure, I know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your data structure slightly, this is a trivial problem for the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> lst = [1]
>>> combine = [["a", "b", "c"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
>>> import itertools
>>> [lst+list(item) for item in itertools.product(*combine)]
[[1, 'a', 'A'], [1, 'a', 'B'], [1, 'a', 'C'], [1, 'b', 'A'], [1, 'b', 'B'], 
 [1, 'b', 'C'], [1, 'c', 'A'], [1, 'c', 'B'], [1, 'c', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = [1]
>>> combine = [["a", "b", "c"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
>>> list(product(*[lst]+combine))
[(1, 'a', 'A'), (1, 'a', 'B'), (1, 'a', 'C'), (1, 'b', 'A'), (1, 'b', 'B'), (1, 'b', 'C'), (1, 'c', 'A'), (1, 'c', 'B'), (1, 'c', 'C')]
```

you could also use

```
list(product(lst, replace_lst1, replace_lst2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use itertools.product, plus a test to replace the ? by the value :

```
lst = [1, '?2','?3']
replace_lst1 = ['a','b','c']
replace_lst2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
res = []
#put as many replace_lst as you need here
for values in itertools.product(replace_lst1, replace_lst2):
    val_iter = iter(values)
    res.append([x if str(x).find('?') == -1 else next(val_iter) for x in lst])
```

The use of val_iter allows for the ?* to be placed anywhere (but not in any order, though).

Comment: Thank you all for the responses! `itertools.product` is exactly what I needed! Cheers!